# Getting input as mm/dd and separating it

Tags: c++, date, c++11, g++, atoi

I've been working on a project. Where you get the input as:
mm/dd as an example 12/30. But hey, there's the challenging part.

I tried to use atoi and stoi... actually here's the code:

```
Date::Date(const char* date){
string s;
s = date;


string delimiter = "/";
auto start = s.begin();
auto finish = s.find(delimiter);
if (finish == s.npos){}
else{
    int mth = stoi(s.substr(0, finish));
    s = s.substr(finish + 1);
    month = Months[mth-1];
}

int c = atoi(s.c_str());
day = c;
}
```

Now, it takes the input from the user. Wheter it's `12/05` or `12 / 05` or even `12   /    05` notice the spaces and stores them into the private values month and day. It works just fine! However...

On Ubuntu while compiling it I had to use -std=c++11 because otherwise it gave the error `Date.cpp:20:24: error: ‘atoi’ was not declared in this scope`

Same also applies for stoi. Anyway, I wonder if I can do it in any other way which the default g++ would accept.

Where I can convert a string to a number, without using atoi nor the stoi, while ignoring spaces and the slash '/' symbol. Still making it work fine.

Any ideas is welcome, good luck!

Edit:

```
Date::Date(const char* date){
string s;
s = date;

long i;
i = 0;
while (*date >= '0' && *date <= '9')
{
    i = i * 10 + (*date - '0');
    date++;
}

month = Months[i-1];

day = i;
}
```

Now I got this and it reads everything just fine and sets the month to **December** and well... since I don't know how to read past the slash icon... day to 12 aswell. How do I read beyond the slash icon now and store it for day?

Comment: Why are you using both `stoi` and `atoi`?

Comment: @Holt I'm relatively new to C++, I just left them in their final form where it worked just fine. However, I want to use **none** of them! Do you have any idea how do I do it? Without getting into trouble with spaces and '/' ?

Comment: @Holt they're included in the header file. I can also compile it and run the program with g++ -std=c++11 in Ubuntu. It works amazingly fine. The only thing is, I want to get rid of them and never use them. It's **the challenge**.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question... `atoi` is not a C++11 function, so it should be available even without `-std=c++11`. Otherwize you could try [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol), but why do you want to avoid C++11?

Comment: @Holt to learn better and understand better. For example, to see how atoi actually works. I made this now.

`Date::Date(const char* date){

 long i;
 i = 0;
 while (*date >= '0' && *date <= '9')
 {
  i = i * 10 + (*date - '0');
  date++;
 }

 month = Months[i-1];

 day = i;
}`

It stores the date as 12/12 though... since I also made day equal to i... the problem is... I don't know how to grab past the slash symbol.

12/30 as an example. How do I grab past that slash?

Edit: Also stoi is a c++11 function. That's why I had to use it, I believe. Anyway, let's get rid of them!

Comment: Well, then you just have to skip space (see `std::isspace`), then check if you get a `/`, skip space again, and do another conversion to `int`... I don't really understand what is your issue here actually?

Comment: If you had a fairly up-to-date compiler (>= GCC 6) the default standard
would be C++14 (the current standard), not C++98. There is no educational merit in insisting
on writing C++, in 2017, according to the Standard of 1998 as opposed
to the Standard of 2011. If you are interested in knowing how the functions
of the Standard Library work, in GCC, [the source
code](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc) will show you. Your own alternative implementations won't.